# Unicorn says "Error opening file for reading: Permission denied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, unicorn

I'm running a rails 3 application running on unicorn, every now and then I get this message:

> Error opening file for reading: Permission denied

and that's it. I don't know what file or what component is trying to opening it. It doesn't happen on each request or any other external event that I can figure out.

Any ideas what might be going on or how to try to figure it out?

I tried searching for "Error opening file for reading" on all the gems I'm using, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started seeing this from time to time in Passenger logs after upgrading to ubuntu 12.04.
I narrowed it down to some image processing and it apparently comes from Ubuntu's patches to `libjpeg-turbo` library.

It is trying to access `/proc/self/auxv` to determine some system capabilities, but that proc file seems not to be always readable, presumably after a process setuid()s to another user when dropping privileges.

As far as I can tell, the library works even if that fails, so it shouldn't cause any major issues.

There seems to be a related bug report at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1014487

Answer (score -2):

I started running following command in Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after running above command, the "Error opening file for reading: Permission denied" was solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, *”run x command and it will solve the problem"* is pretty fair answer.

Comment: @brasofilo But it has nothing to do with Unicorn/Passenger as such, it even provides an apt-get example (?!); this is the sort of stuff you don't need to run as root (running web services as root, what could possible go wrong?). In other words, it's a random comment about permission denied errors, which IMHO doesn't really provide an answer to the stated question.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, oh, there was more to it than I read at first, thanks for clarifying. . . . . . Please, Seagle Dorjee, take this site [tour] and read the guides [answer] and [ask].